# Dynamic Field Name Using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I'm trying to print the list of fields in each schema and table dynamically. since I need a print for further references not a table, I used a cursor to print them out, as follows:

```
DECLARE AutoFields CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
OPEN AutoFields
DECLARE @TableSchema NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100)

FETCH NEXT
FROM AutoFields
INTO @TableSchema,@TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXECUTE('
            SELECT COLUMN_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=@TableSchema
            AND TABLE_NAME=@TableName
           ')
     FETCH NEXT
     FROM AutoFields
     INTO @TableSchema,@TableName
END 

CLOSE AutoFields
DEALLOCATE AutoFields
```

But i get this error over and over again:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@TableSchema".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just write

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Also i think you need this in CURSOR

```
DECLARE AutoFields CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables --Not Columns
```

Comment: because as i explained, i want the print of them for further usage, not a table with rows.

Comment: @Miss.Alpha - your `execute('..') ` doing same thing as what my first query is doing. Not sure where you are printing it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the variables to concatenate your dynamic string, not be a part of it.   Like this:

```
EXECUTE('
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= ''' + @TableSchema + '''
        AND TABLE_NAME= ''' + @TableName + '''
       ')
```

Comment: There's still a problem: Invalid column name 'x'. 'x' is the name of all the table names!

Comment: I'm not following you.   What part of the code is this error occurring on?   I don't see anywhere in the code you posted that it could happen.